# Visualforce page to hide recent items for a custom object is not working for Lightning and salesforce 1

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I have created a visualforce page to hide recent items for a custom object which is not working for Lightning and salesforce 1. Please suggest any code changes or workaround.

```
<apex:page standardController="Leave__c" recordSetVar="a" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Leave__c.List,$ObjectType.Leave__c)}" />
```

Comment: VisualForce should work in lightning. How do you include it? in a tab? in the lightning page layout? in the regular record page layout?

Comment: Yes it is included through tab

Comment: Did you add the tab to your menu or app? do you see it in SF classic?

Comment: It works fine on classic full website however not working on salesforce 1.